# Trying to send an object to Spring boot via ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, rest

I'm trying to send this post object to spring boot but I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>> com.example.RegisterLogin.controller.RegisterController.registerHandler(java.lang.Object)
```

I can't understand why.

This is my code in Java:

```
   @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String,String>> registerHandler(@RequestBody Object registerDTO) {
        log.info("User: {}",registerDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(registerService.saveUser((RegisterDTO) registerDTO));
    }
```

This is my code in reactjs:

```
 export class RegisterService{
        save(user){
         console.log({ method: 'POST', headers: { accept: 'application/json', body: JSON.stringify({registerDTO: user})}})
       fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/register', { method: 'POST', headers: { accept: 'application/json', body: JSON.stringify({registerDTO: user})}})
       .then(data => console.log(data.json())) // Parsing the data into a JavaScript object
       .then(json => alert(JSON.stringify(json))) 
       }
 }
```

I can see via console it sends this:
[image: errorConsole]

find out the problem, but there is another one
with React send me this object: (Spring doesn't like it)

```
{registerDTO={name=w, dsurname=wd, age=3, sex=MALE, role=USER, email=ijwd@wdmiwd.it, password=wdkledml}}
```

With postman I get this and everything works:

```
{name=edfew, surname=feefewe, email=eeffe@gmail.com, password=efefefe, age=23, sex=MALE, role=USER}
```

Does somebody know how to fix it please

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are returning the result of the console.log instead of the promise from the .json() function. You need to return the promise from the .json() function.

```js
.then(data => console.log(data.json()))

//should become:

.then(data => data.json())
```

Comment: now Srping doesn't read the body, any help for that?

Comment: @Alex if you have made progress or are now seeing a new error message, please update your original question to reflect this.